# Restfull Controllers in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm try do that:

```
class ProjectsController extends BaseController {

public $restful = true;

public function get_admin_index()
{
    echo 'get admin index'; exit;
}
```

But doesn't work.

If I try put this Controller in **app/controller/admin/** folder, and change the method to only **get_index**, doesn't work too.

Comment: Quick Tip: Echoing data is not optimal in Laravel. You should always `return` something, like a string, or a `Response` (`return Response::make('get admin index')`).

Comment: @Michael Yes, I know that. Is just a example, I never use echo, or, only in debug test. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All methods in L4 are camel case so get_index() would be getIndex(). With that said I believe you will want to look at this [Resourceful controllers](http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers).

Comment: Doesn't work. My controller is in app/controller/admin/ProjectsController.php, and my route: Route::get('admin/projects', 'admin.ProjectsController@index'); I try with "/" or "\", but doesn't work too.

Comment: I don't think that works anymore, you have to fully qualify the name off the method..the restful method has become resourceful and that is what they want you to use I guess..

Comment: @c What's the difference between RESTful and Resourceful controllers in Laravel? I can only find information about the latter.